# Unable to use delimiter using script in mariadb

Tags: database, mariadb, liquibase

I have a script file(named test.sql) in which I have written a loop along with other sql statments prior to the loop as well as after the loop:

```
DELIMITER //
FOR REC IN ( select count(*)from user_preference)
DO
UPDATE user_preference SET ID = nextval(USERPREF);
END FOR;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

The ./sh script contains:

```
id: 3.36.0
     comment: user deletion changes
     author: testuser
     changes:
      - sqlFile:
         
         encoding: utf8

         path: /db-scripts-${database}/test.sql
         relativeToChangelogFile: true
         splitStatements: true
```

This script is not working when I am trying to execute it from ./sh file (liquibase) however if I write these statements to the mariadb directly it is getting executed. If anyone can help me understand , why this behaviour ?

Comment: I don't see a `./sh` file in your question, and I also don't see how you run this file. How can I then give any advice?

Comment: ./sh file is nothing but the script which is executing the other scripts well . In that script only the path of .sql file is mentioned and nothing else.

Comment: I don't know what _mentioning a path_ means, but why you don't you post the relevant part of the script? At least we need to see how mariadb is invoked.  Also, post any output you see (error messages or others).

Comment: I have made the edits @user1934428

Comment: Now you finally reveal at least that you are using _liquidbase_, and that you are calling your SQL file from there. People knowing liquidbase  (I don't) may now be able to help you.  What I still don't understand is (1) why you tagged your question by _bash_ and _shell_ (since no shell code is present), and (2) where in your liquidbase definition you state that this SQL code should be run by mariadb (and not, say, oracle, or informix or something else).

Comment: Why were you asking the details when you don't know ABCD of this question . I only mentioned a part or relevant part of the shell script not the entire one.

Comment: Because you did not mention _liquidbase_ initially. I thought you have a bash script which performs the query - and this would have  been something I know about. And please remove your _bash_ and _shell_ tags, to not confuse other Stackoverflow users. Correct tagging of the questions ensures that those people will be attracted who have knowledge of the subject.